# C# Build anonymous type from array string

Tags: c#, reflection, automapper, system.reflection, anonymous-types

I'm looking for a way to build an anonymous type from an object where it's property names match those in a given string array.  Something like:

```
//Current Way:
    var anonObject = primaryObject.Select(m=> new {m.property1, m.property2, m.property3, m.property4, ...etc});
//Ideal Way:
    var propertyArray= new string["property1","property3"];
    var anonObject = primaryObject.Select(m=> new { /* Something here where we step through primaryObject.GetProperties() and only choose the ones where the name is contained in the above array */ });
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Anonymous types are still statically typed. What you're after would not be statically typed, so it can't be an anonymous type. The logical choice would be a `Dictionary<string, object>` (or more specific than `object` if it's not homogeneous), or if you have to interface with something that wants an object an `ExpandoObject`. Alternatively, if the string array can vary but not at runtime, you can consider code generation (like source generators) to create the desired type at compile time. There are also various dynamic LINQ libraries, but I have no experience with those.

Comment: How to you plan to use an anonymous type where the properties are not known at compile time? Meaning, what do you _do_ with that anonymously typed object? I strongly suspect there's a different way to do what you want to do without using "dynamic" anonymous types.

Comment: the properties will be known at compile time.  I've simplified this to make more sense, but basically i only want the properties that match another object's properties.  The array it will compare against is just the 'getproperties' of a different object

Comment: Then it sounds like you're more after something like AutoMapper, nothing much to do with LINQ.

Comment: no, I don't have to use LINQ in my case (other than the select statement example), but i wouldn't think this would be complicated enough to require adding an additional package.  Plus, i'm not sure of the way to do this via automapper anyways

Comment: You don't *need* AutoMapper, per se -- you can just use `Type.GetProperties()` and `PropertyInfo.GetValue()/SetValue()` yourself, but writing such reflection code is never comfortable and typically will perform worse than specialized solutions anyway.

Comment: i understand the performance issues, that won't be much of a problem here.  I know how to getproperties, i give it as an example in my code above.   The whole point of my question though is how do i get those properties, filter out the ones i don't want, and then build an anonymous type from that

Comment: You can't do this... As other wrote there is compile time and runtime...

Comment: Again: you *cannot* build an anonymous type, because the structure of that *must* be known at compile time, and the contents of an array are not known at compile time (or, even when they are, that knowledge cannot be used to declare a type). Anonymous types are just shorthand for an implicitly declared class that you do not give a name, but they otherwise work exactly like normal classes. What you *can* do is assign the properties of "another object" that you said the list of properties actually comes from, using a simple `foreach` loop over that object's properties.

Comment: You can also use automapper... Just make a type with desired properties which are subset of source properties and map it... Edit: wait, there is automapper tag in the question so why don't you use it?

Comment: You can use custom attribute to generate those class from array of string(passed ar attribute parameter) ... Search for source generator